# How do I disable automount for a synced folder in vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am working on a provisioning script for vagrant that would need to perform some operations before the synced folders are mounted.
The documentation specifies a way to plain disable mounts, using the `disabled: true` flag, but there are references to a way to define shares but not automount them.

Thread reference:
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1004

Comment in the code (line 55):
https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/providers/virtualbox/synced_folder.rb

```
# If no guest path is specified, then automounting is disabled              
machine.ui.detail(I18n.t("vagrant.actions.vm.share_folders.nomount_entry", hostpath: data[:hostpath]))
```

The thread suggests using `nil` as the guest path, for instance

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", nil, id: 'application_root'
```

but doing so in vagrant 1.7.2 returns an error when trying to run the provisioning.

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:
* The shared folder guest path must be absolute:
```

Any thoughts?

I am only concerned about the vbox provider in my case.

Comment: Maybe explain why you need the synced folders only after provisioning has happened. There may be an alternative fix.

Comment: During the provisioning I might have to run a kernel update, which means that if the machine is halted, the synced folder won't be able to be mounted because the vbox kernel modules would not have been built for the correct version. So the idea is on each vagrant up to check whether the modules are loaded. If not, build them, and finally mount the synced folders manually.